# Swift mailer Sending mail from gmail is working but not from web mail

Tags: php

If I send  mail from gmail account like someone@gmail.com to another gmail or yahoo account it works
but
If i send mail from gmail or yahoo account "someone@gmail.com" to company mail account like someone@companyname.net  it's not going to work.

```
<?php
    require_once __dir__.'/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
    $password='nag';
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25);

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    // Create a message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

      // Give the message a subject
      ->setSubject('Password Recovery')

      // Set the From address with an associative array
      ->setFrom(array('someone@company.net' => 'someone')) //change this mail id to gmail mail id

      // Set the To addresses with an associative array
      ->setTo(array('someone2@company.net' => 'someone')) //change this mail id to gmail mail id

      // Give it a body
      ->setBody('Below is your temporary password. Please make sure to login in immediately and change it to a password of your choice.\n'.$password);
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
    if($result){
      echo 'mail sent';
    }
```

I need to change some settings in company mail server or i need to do something else  please help.